# What do the vertical bars around a variable mean in Big O notation?

Tags: big-o

I know in mathematics vertical bars can mean absolute value. 
Example `|n|`.

I have seen it used in Big O notation as well. For example take a look at the worst case performance of breadth first search: `O(|V| + |E|)`.

What do the vertical bars mean here? How is the above example different from: `O(V + E)`?

If they mean absolute value as well, how could we have negative number of vertices or edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means Cardinality. That means the number of elements in the enclosed set of objects.

```
|V| = number of objects in V.
```